# How can I add a listener for when my S3PutObjectRequest has completed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading to Amazon S3 using the iOS SDK which is working great but I want to be able to trigger a method when the load is completed.

Here is my code:

```
AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY] autorelease];
// Create the picture bucket.
[s3 createBucket:[[[S3CreateBucketRequest alloc] initWithName:[Constants pictureBucket]] autorelease]];
NSString *picName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", PICTURE_NAME, counter];
// Upload image data.  Remember to set the content type.
S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:picName inBucket:[Constants pictureBucket]] autorelease];
NSLog(@"------------ SUBMITTING img :%@", picName);
por.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
por.data        = imageData;
counter++;                   
// Put the image data into the specified s3 bucket and object.
[s3 putObject:por];
```

Any help much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Amazon SDK Docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AmazonServiceResponse.html) it seems that you get an `S3PutObjectResponse`

so

```
S3PutObjectResponse *response  = [s3 putObject:por];
if ([response isFinishedLoading]) {
    //do something
}
```

or maybe you are searching for `connectionDidFinishLoading:` which is a delegate method from NSURLConnection which it seem they use accordingly to [AmazonServiceResponse Class Reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AmazonServiceResponse.html#//api/name/connectionDidFinishLoading%3a)

in you .h file declare that you conform to the delegate protocol of NSURLConnection

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```

in your .m file implement the delegate methods you want

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
      //do your stuff here
}
```

and tell the NSURLConnection that you handle the delegate methods in your .m file

```
S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:picName inBucket:[Constants pictureBucket]] autorelease];
por.urlRequest.delegate = self; // this is important !!!
```

In general you should get used to work with delegates since they are often used throug the hole iOS SDK !!

You can find additional docu here: [Delegates and Data Sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)

Comment: Thanks Pfitz, your example works great, you couldn't point me to an example of the other technique using connectionDidFinishLoading could you? Apologies, I am pretty new to this!

Comment: fantastic, thankyou! I would not have figured that out myself

Comment: hmm, I've just tried this but I can't seem to access the property        por.urlRequest.delegate, I have the error 'property 'delegate' not found on 'AmazonURlRequest'     You are right I need to learn delegates! will read through the doc, thanks again

Comment: I've found I can get delegation to work using this code to set the delegate, though I am left with an unused variable:   NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:por.urlRequest delegate:self];     I will read up on delegates!

Comment: i haven't used the amazon sdk by myself. but it clearly states there should be a property delegate - u can try maybe 'por.delegate = self';

Comment: por.urlRequest.delegate = self; doesn't work, use por.delegate = self; works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just have one more thing to add to the comments ( I know I am stepping out of conduct here but rep prevents me from commenting). I run these two lines just to be safe, as I have found the first does not retain its value consistently:

```
    por.delegate = self;
    [por setDelegate:self];
```

As you are a newbie like me, delegates are essentially handlers where the object looks when it calls obligatory methods that are sometimes required or not. If you set a delegate to `self`, it means that the putObjectRequest will reference obligatory methods on `self` when they are called, such as the method in Pfitz's answer. For `UITableView`, an example of a delegate method is `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` where the object, `UITableView` will reference `self` to look for a method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in order to populate its object's cell queue.